# How to insert a row with a type in a table(postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql

I would like to know how to insert a row that contains a type, I was researching all over the internet but I could not find how to do it.

```
CREATE TYPE t_name 
 AS(name char(50),
  surname1 char(50),
  surname2 char(50));

CREATE TABLE Employees (
 id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
 name t_name,
 departament int,
 salary real);
```

I would like to insert a row but I don't find how.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO Employees(id, name, departament, salary)
 VALUES(1,t_nom['name1','surname1','surname2']),10,20000.00);
```

(The above code is not working).

I'm using postgreSQL.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO Employees(id, name, departament, salary) VALUES(1,ROW('name1','surname1','surname2'),10,20000.00);`? Based on [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-DECLARING)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It works thank you!

Comment: It also works like that: VALUES(1,('name1','surname1','surname2'),10,20000.00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-DECLARING) composite types are created using the `ROW()` function. Therefore your `INSERT` statement should be

```
INSERT INTO Employees (id, name, departament, salary)
  VALUES (1, ROW('name1', 'surname1', 'surname2'), 10, 20000.00);
```